# Difference between Bravo and Buono

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

What is the difference between `bravo` and `buono`? They both mean "good", right? Are there any rules to use them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Bravo* generally expresses skills:

> Suo figlio è bravo in matematica: His/Her/Your son is good at Math

Also in manners and behavior

> Suo figlio è un bravo ragazzo: His/Her/Your son is a good kid
>
> Il tuo cane è proprio bravo, non abbaia mai : Your dog is really good, it never barks

*Buono* expresses quality:

> Un uomo buono: a good man (kind and friendly, but not necessarily skilled)
>
> Questa torta è molto buona! : This cake is very good!

As a general rule ([from this link](http://italingua.ning.com/profiles/blogs/bello-buono-bravo-bene)), *bravo* goes only with people and animals.

The link adds also *bello* and *bene* to the mix.

Comment: "Un uomo buono" si usa raramente, probabilmente per l'alliterazione antiestetica della "u". É sempre preferibile "un buon'uomo"

Comment: @Bruno9779: “È”, non *“É”.
“buon uomo”, non *“buon'uomo”.
E anche sull'opinione in sé ho miei dubbi, [condivisi da Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=un+buon+uomo%2Cun+uomo+buono&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cun%20buon%20uomo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cun%20uomo%20buono%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: is bravo=clever?